# Difference between public variable and getVar/setVar?

Tags: java, c++, object-oriented-analysis

In java, it is recommended to declare a variable as private and access it using a public function getVar() and set it using public function putVar().

```
public void setVar(int y)
{
   this.x=y;  //x is a private variable of class

}

public int getVar(){

   return this.x;
}
```

Why cant we just declare the variables as public and use it using object.var anywhere. In anycase, the members of the object are accessible. In one case using getVar() and in other case using object.var. Then why the get()/set() is used everywhere?

Comment: this will explain it orders better than I can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters

Comment: Learn about inheritance, you will understand more.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Ben. I tried to search before posting but couldnt find it :)